# How to fill pandas dataframe with max() values

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe where each day starts at 7:00 and ends at 22:10 in 5 minute intervals.

 In the df are around 200 days (weekend days and some specific days are excluded)

```
        Date                Time    Volume
    0   2019-09-03 07:00:00 70000   778
    1   2019-09-03 07:05:00 70500   1267
    2   2019-09-03 07:10:00 71000   1208
    3   2019-09-03 07:15:00 71500   715
    4   2019-09-03 07:20:00 72000   372
```

I need another column, let's call it 'lastdayVolume', with the max value of Volume of the prior day
For example, in 2019-09-03 (between 7:00 and 22:10) the maximum volume value in a single row is 50000, then I need in every row of 2019-09-04 the value 50000 in column 'lastdayVolume'.
How would you do this without decreasing the lenght of the dataframe?

Comment: Since your problem is specific to `previous days`, you should probably include a sample data that have at least 2 days.

Comment: Yes that would have been helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
df.resample('1D', on='Date').max()
```

This should give you one row per day with the maximal value at this day.

EDIT: To combine that with the old Data, you can use a left join. Its a bit messy but

```
pd.merge(df, df.resample('1D', on='Date')['Volume'].max().rename('lastdayVolume'), left_on=pd.to_datetime((df['Date'] - pd.Timedelta('1d')).dt.date), right_index=True, how='left')
In [54]: pd.merge(df, df.resample('1D', on='Date')['Volume'].max().rename('lastdayVolume'), left_on=pd.to_datetime((df['Date'] - pd.Timedelta('1d')).dt.date), right_index=True, how='left')                       
Out[54]: 
                 Date   Time  Volume  lastdayVolume
0 2019-09-03 07:00:00  70000     778          800.0
1 2019-09-03 07:05:00  70500    1267          800.0
2 2019-09-03 07:10:00  71000    1208          800.0
3 2019-09-03 07:15:00  71500     715          800.0
4 2019-09-03 07:20:00  72000     372          800.0
0 2019-09-02 08:00:00  70000     800            NaN
```

seems to work out.

Equivalently you can use the slightly shorter

```
df.join(df.resample('1D', on='Date')['Volume'].max().rename('lastdayVolume'), on=pd.to_datetime((df['Date'] - pd.Timedelta('1d')).dt.date))
```

here.

The first DataFrame is your old one, the second is the one I calculated above (with appropriate renaming). For the values to merge on you use your `'Date'` column which contains timestamps, offset it by one day and converted to an actual date on the left. On the right simply use the index.
The left join ensures you don't accidentally drop rows if you have no transactions the day before.

EDIT 2: To find out that maximum in a certain timerange, you can use

```
df.set_index('Date').between_time('15:30:00', '22:10:00')
```

to filter the DataFrame. Afterwards resample as before

```
df.join(df.set_index('Date').between_time('15:30:00', '22:10:00').resample('1D')...
```

where the `on` parameter in the resample is no longer necessary as the Date went into the index.

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention in the question that the length of the dataframe can't be altered

Comment: You would still calculate the maximum the same way and combine it with the old dataframe via a join. I edited the answer.

Comment: It works! Thank you! Do you have a solution to get the max not from the entire day, but from 15:30 to 22:10 from the previous day?

Comment: This question keeps on giving ;) I editied it again.

Comment: unfortunately both solutions don't work on my big dataframe. I get NaN on about a fifth of all rows.